# Unity 2D draggable movement control

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to add a draggable-movement control thing (attached image) like Fifa mobile game in my 2D app.

I searched a lot for the idea or a basic tutorial or relevant Unity asset. But didn't find one.

Help me with an example or URL.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this if you would like, it works on web and mobile

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class JoyStick : MonoBehaviour {

    public Texture areaTexture;
    public Texture touchTexture;
    public Vector2 joystickPosition = new Vector2( 50f,50f);
    public Vector2 speed = new Vector2(2,100);
    public float zoneRadius=100f;
    public float touchSize = 30;
    public float deadZone=20;
    public float touchSizeCoef=0;
    protected Vector2 joystickAxis;
    protected Vector2 joystickValue;
    public Vector2 joyTouch;
    private Vector2 _joystickCenter;
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector2 _smoothing = new Vector2(20f,20f);
    public Vector2 Smoothing 
    {
        get {
            return this._smoothing;
        }
        set {
            _smoothing = value;
            if (_smoothing.x<0.1f){
                _smoothing.x=0.1f;
            }
            if (_smoothing.y<0.1){
                _smoothing.y=0.1f;   
            }
        }
    }
    private int _joystickIndex=-1;
    private bool _enaReset;
    private bool _enaZoom;

    void Start () 
    {
        zoneRadius = Screen.width*0.07f;
        touchSize = Screen.width*0.07f;
        joystickPosition = new Vector2(Screen.width*0.12f,Screen.width*0.12f);
        _joystickCenter = joystickPosition;
        _enaReset=false;
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer || Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) 
        {
            foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
            {
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled) 
                {
                    if (_joystickIndex==touch.fingerId){
                        _joystickIndex=-1;
                        _enaReset=true;
                    }
                }

                if(_joystickIndex==touch.fingerId)
                {
                    OnTouchDown(touch.position);
                }
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    if (((Vector2)touch.position - _joystickCenter).sqrMagnitude < Mathf.Pow((zoneRadius+touchSizeCoef/2),2))
                    {
                        _joystickIndex = touch.fingerId;
                    }
                }
            }

            UpdateJoystick();
            if(_enaReset)
            {
                ResetJoystick();
            }
        }
        else
        { 
            if (Input.GetButtonUp ("Fire1"))     
            {
                _joystickIndex=-1;
                _enaReset=true;
            }
            if(_joystickIndex==1)
            {
                OnTouchDown(Input.mousePosition);
            }
            if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1") ) 
            {
                if (((Vector2)Input.mousePosition - _joystickCenter).sqrMagnitude <Mathf.Pow( (zoneRadius+touchSizeCoef/2),2))
                {
                    _joystickIndex = 1;

                }

            }
            if(_enaReset)
            {
                ResetJoystick();
            }

            UpdateJoystick();

        }

    }




    private void UpdateJoystick()
    { 
        if (joyTouch.sqrMagnitude>deadZone*deadZone)
        {

            joystickAxis = Vector2.zero;
            if (Mathf.Abs(joyTouch.x)> deadZone)
            {
                joystickAxis = new Vector2( (joyTouch.x -(deadZone*Mathf.Sign(joyTouch.x)))/(zoneRadius-touchSizeCoef-deadZone),joystickAxis.y);

            }
            else
            {
                joystickAxis = new Vector2( joyTouch.x /(zoneRadius-touchSizeCoef),joystickAxis.y);

            }
            if (Mathf.Abs(joyTouch.y)> deadZone)
            {
                joystickAxis = new Vector2( joystickAxis.x,(joyTouch.y-(deadZone*Mathf.Sign(joyTouch.y)))/(zoneRadius-touchSizeCoef-deadZone));
            }
            else{
                joystickAxis = new Vector2( joystickAxis.x,joyTouch.y/(zoneRadius-touchSizeCoef));  
            }

        }
        else{
            joystickAxis = new Vector2(0,0);
        }
        Vector2 realvalue = new Vector2(  speed.x*joystickAxis.x,speed.y*joystickAxis.y);
        joystickValue=realvalue;
        //print(realvalue);

    }

    void OnTouchDown(Vector2 position)
    {
        joyTouch  = new Vector2( position.x, position.y) - _joystickCenter;
        if ((joyTouch/(zoneRadius-touchSizeCoef)).sqrMagnitude > 1)
        {
            joyTouch.Normalize();
            joyTouch *= zoneRadius-touchSizeCoef;
        }
        //print(joyTouch);
    }


    private void ResetJoystick()
    {
        if (joyTouch.sqrMagnitude>0.1)
        {
            joyTouch = new Vector2( joyTouch.x - joyTouch.x*_smoothing.x*Time.deltaTime, joyTouch.y - joyTouch.y*_smoothing.y*Time.deltaTime);    
        }
        else{
            joyTouch = Vector2.zero;
            _enaReset=false;
        }
    }
    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.DrawTexture( new Rect(_joystickCenter.x -zoneRadius ,Screen.height- _joystickCenter.y-zoneRadius,zoneRadius*2,zoneRadius*2), areaTexture,ScaleMode.ScaleToFit,true);
        GUI.DrawTexture( new Rect(_joystickCenter.x+(joyTouch.x -touchSize) ,Screen.height-_joystickCenter.y-(joyTouch.y+touchSize),touchSize*2,touchSize*2), touchTexture,ScaleMode.ScaleToFit,true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx for the support. Will check & let you know.

Comment: +1. Man that really helped a lot lot. :) Wish I could give you a bounty. Thanx a ton.